# Remix Loader Function is not executed everytime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I built tabbing functionality in my web app using Links and an Outlet with subroutes

```
const { currentTab } = useLoaderData();

function tabClassName(tab: string) {
    if (currentTab == tab) { return "is-active"; }
    return "";
}

return ([
    <div className="tabs is-centered m-5 pr-5 pl-5">
        <ul>
            <li className={tabClassName("tab1")}><Link to="tab1">one</Link></li>
            <li className={tabClassName("tab2")}><Link to="tab2">two</Link></li>
            <li className={tabClassName("tab3")}><Link to="tab3">three</Link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>,
    <Outlet></Outlet>
]);
```

The loader function supplies the component with the current subroute like this:

```
const parts = new URL(request.url).pathname.split("/");
const tab = parts.pop() || parts.pop() || ""; // get final part of path /settings/tab1 -> tab1
if (tab === "settings") {
    return redirect("/settings/tab1");
}
return json<LoaderData>({ currentTab: tab });
```

When I click the links the correct route is loaded instantly. However, the css class is only applied after clicking the same link a second time. I found out that the loader function is only executed after the second click. How can i force remix to make a server request again? or should i use client side js for this? I cant use the NavLink  component because of the way my css framework is structured.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm debugging similar surprising where the router changes the URL but I don't see my `console.log` inside `function loader(...)`

Comment: Have you tried using the useNavigate hook? If you havent, can you check if it produces the same behavior.